# Problems arranging data in ascending order using group by and order by

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to get shipment date in ascending order with respect to shipment number and item number, but not able to do it using following query

```
Select s.shipment_date, s.shipment_number,i.item_number
  from Shipment_Item si
  Inner Join Shipment s on s.shipment_id = si.shipment_id
  Inner Join Item_master i on i.item_id = si.item_id
  where s.shipment_date between '1/1/14' and '12/31/14'
  group by i.item_number, s.shipment_number, s.shipment_date
```

If I use this query

```
  Select s.shipment_date, s.shipment_number,i.item_number
  from Shipment_Item si
  Inner Join Shipment s on s.shipment_id = si.shipment_id
  Inner Join Item_master i on i.item_id = si.item_id
  where s.shipment_date between '1/1/14' and '12/31/14'
  group by i.item_number, s.shipment_number
  order by s.shipment_date
```

I am getting the following 
Column 'Shipment.Shipment_Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You have to do what it says: put the shipment_date into the SELECT list with an aggregate function, such as MAX(shipment_date) or MIN(shipment_date) and then sort on it.

Comment: @Joel I did that, it gives the following. Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Don't add it to the GROUP BY, add it to the ORDER BY:  ORDER BY MAX(s.shipment_date)

Comment: @Joel, I tried that too and got this message. Column 'Shipment.Shipment_Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields in the group by clause do not specify an ordering of the output.  It only specifies the grouping.  If you want them grouped and ordered you have to put the columns in both clauses:

```
Select s.shipment_date, s.shipment_number,i.item_number
  from Shipment_Item si
  Inner Join Shipment s on s.shipment_id = si.shipment_id
  Inner Join Item_master i on i.item_id = si.item_id
  where s.shipment_date between '1/1/14' and '12/31/14'
  group by i.item_number, s.shipment_number, s.shipment_date 
  order by i.item_number, s.shipment_number, s.shipment_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by clause should be like:   group by i.item_number, s.shipment_number, s.shipment_date

Comment: That is what I did in first query above, it orders irregularly